# Node.js Query with Dynamic SQL Conditions Not Returning Expected Results

Tags: node.js, postgresql, fastify

Hello StackOverflow Community,

I'm facing an issue with a Node.js application where I'm constructing a dynamic SQL query with conditional logic. The query is supposed to return products based on certain conditions, but it behaves unexpectedly depending on how the conditions are included in the query.

The conditions I'm working with are as follows:

```
cond1 = 'EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM product_variant_values
  WHERE product_variant_id = pv.id AND (option_value_id = 44)
) AND EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM product_variant_values
  WHERE product_variant_id = pv.id AND (option_value_id = 38)
)'

cond2 = 'EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM product_attribute_values
  WHERE product_id = p.id AND (attribute_value_id = 33)
) AND EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM product_attribute_values
  WHERE product_id = p.id AND (attribute_value_id = 31)
)'
```

When I directly insert these conditions into the SQL query, it works perfectly and returns the expected products. I've verified that the conditions variable contains the correct SQL snippet (as mentioned above) by logging it to the console. However, when included in the query via template literals, it doesn't yield the expected results.

```
WHERE // ... [other conditions]
AND EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM product_variant_values
  WHERE product_variant_id = pv.id AND (option_value_id = 44)
) AND EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM product_variant_values
  WHERE product_variant_id = pv.id AND (option_value_id = 38)
)
AND EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM product_attribute_values
  WHERE product_id = p.id AND (attribute_value_id = 33)
) AND EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM product_attribute_values
  WHERE product_id = p.id AND (attribute_value_id = 31)
)
```

However, when I try to include these conditions dynamically using a variable, like so:

`WHERE // ... [other conditions] AND ${cond1} AND ${cond2}`

the query does not return any products.

Could someone please help me understand why this is happening and how to resolve it? Is there a specific way to handle dynamic SQL conditions in Node.js that I'm missing?

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

In my attempts to solve this issue, I have experimented with an approach where I created a separate queryParameters object to hold my dynamic conditions along with other necessary parameters for the query. Here's how I structured it:

```
const queryParameters = {
  vrConditionsParam: vrConditions,
  attrConditionsParam: attrConditions,
};
```

I then tried to incorporate these parameters into my query using template literals, assuming that it would allow me to inject the dynamic conditions properly. Here's a snippet of how I used the queryParameters object in the query:

`WHERE // ... [other conditions] AND ${queryParameters.vrConditionsParam} AND ${queryParameters.attrConditionsParam}` 
Additionally, it's important to note that I am unable to use certain methods like this.db.raw or db.query in my current environment. The relevant packages for these methods are not installed, and since I'm working on a shared project, I have to adhere to the existing setup and constraints. Therefore, I am limited to executing queries in the format of await this.db\select...` within Node.js. This limitation is crucial to consider while suggesting any solutions or workarounds.

Comment: It should work. Did you try the raw query in a sql editor first? I would say that the error is in the query itself rather than the code

Comment: I've tried it's working in pgadmin, also working if I directly use the values of conditions